# three.js OrthographicTrackballControls with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, three.js, orthographic

Is it possible to use the `OrthographicTrackballControls` of `three.js` with Angular 4? I tried with:

```
npm install --save three-orthographic-trackball-controls
```

And in my component:

```
import { OrthographicTrackballControls } from 'three-orthographic-trackball-controls';
```

I had no success and no idea on how to do this. I found solutions for `OrbitControls`, but using another `npm` package and `RequireJS`. Any ideas to solve this issue will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See working example of using Angular + Three.js including OrbitControls and ColladaLoader: https://github.com/makimenko/angular-three-examples

Currently, Three.js examples are not included into a module and use them in Angular typescript code could be a little bit tricky. One of solution/workaround could be:

Firstly, include dependencies:

```
three
@types/three
```

Secondly, import in component:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import "./js/EnableThreeExamples";
import "three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls";
import "three/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader";
```

Replace OrbitControls to OrthographicTrackballControls in scene.component.ts. Most probably Camera characteristics should be adjusted as well.

```
this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera);
this.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
this.controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
```

Hope this could help you to start. Also it shows an alternative solution (directly accessing original examples from three.js module without installation of additional NPM packages).